# A Strange Way to Purchase

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A person asks for an item or service, and is told that if they want 2, it'll be free and it would be much faster. The person did not have any medical disorder, nor were they asking for a task to be done to one of their possessions. 
What did they ask for?

Hint:

> The person selling the item or service was clearly joking. Nobody would actually ask for 2 of these, since it would defeat the whole purpose.

Tremendous hint (Will be added if nobody figures it out after a day or so):

> To be added later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say, the person asked for a

> gender transformation

Answer (score 7):

He was a

> guitarist who wanted to have the handedness of his instrument changed.

Doing it once requires some work,

> take out the strings etc.

but changing twice would mean

> it's from right-handed to right-handed which is literally no work at all.

Comment: I think that doesn't fit one of the criteria though:

"nor were they asking for a task to be done to one of their possessions"

Comment: @JGibbers I think that was added after my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Among the several possibilities,

> a [hemispherectomy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemispherectomy)

seems to fit the bill in the most macabre way.

Comment: I've just realized that this puzzle might have multiple answers. I'll upvote each answer that fits and adjust the clues accordingly, but please note that this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Changing the question to disqualify an otherwise valid answer is called "moving the goalposts", and it's deeply frowned upon on PSE. Please try to reformulate the question so that only one answer fits in the first place. (In lateral-thinking puzzles, that's not going to be very easy though, I'm afraid.)

Comment: That is exactly what i meant by "adjust the clues accordingly." Note that I still upvoted you, and you still have a chance to try again, so you didn't lose anything.

Comment: On this site, that won't really fly, since it implicitly means that the question doesn't have a unique correct answer identifiable as such, and that was collectively deemed to constitute grounds for closing.

Answer (score 0):

Might be stretching the meaning of free and faster here but...

> The first person asked the second one to give them a hand (takes time and you can ask to get paid for it), and the second person offered the first person to literally take his two hands instead.